# How can I capture the UserID of the user that has logged in, so I can reference it later?

Tags: java, authentication, hashmap

I'm creating a login system on Java. I have stored the UserID and Password in a Hash Map. When the user logins into the system. they enter the credentials and if it matches the credentials in the Hash Map, the user is logged in.

What I'm trying to do now, is capture which user has logged in via the UserID. The reason is because I want to be able to see which User has pressed a JButton. In order to do this I need to find a way to reference the UserID, of the User who has logged in.

How can I go about this?

This code snippet below is from my Login class, which shows how I allow the user to login

```java
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getSource()==resetButton) {
            userIDField.setText("");
            userPasswordField.setText("");
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==loginButton) {
            
            String userID = userIDField.getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(userPasswordField.getPassword());
            
            if(logininfo.containsKey(userID)) {
                if(logininfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    messageLabel.setText("Login successful");
                    frame.dispose();
                    WelcomePage welcomePage = new WelcomePage(userID);
                }
                else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    messageLabel.setText("Wrong password");                 
                }

            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText("Incorrect, try again");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This code snippet is the from IDandPasswords class, and shows the Hash Map of the UserID and Password

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class IDandPasswords {

    HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    
    IDandPasswords(){
        
        logininfo.put("manager","abc123");
        logininfo.put("user1","abc123");
        logininfo.put("user2","abc123");
        logininfo.put("user3","abc123");
    }
    
    public HashMap getLoginInfo(){
        return logininfo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reproduce a context

It is a white board where we store data in the global life cycle of the application.

One simple way to implements this is to create a class where you have a hashmap of String, Object elements `HashMap<String,Object>` the try to write some methods

Like `initContext` ,`setContextValue(String key, Object value)` ,`Object getContextValue(String key)` ,`getUser()`  ...

Then, try to use a singleton pattern to get it safely to insure it unicity.

About referencing Objects I suggest to use a TypingSafety principle

```
public class ContextKeys{
    public static final String CURRENT_USER = "current_user_key_code_this could be any thing";
    public static final String MY_OTHER_KEY = "application_name"
}
```

Supposing you have a context look like this, you can code it in any fashion you desire. this is a simple idea coding .

```
public class Context {
  private static final HashTable<String,Object> _context ;
  
  public static Object getValueByKey(String key){ return _context.get(key);} 

}
```

The call would be like `Context.getValueByKey(ContextKeys.MY_OTHER_KEY)`

If you dont like the String keys class, you cans use a enum. try to look for this as a  new assignement :) .

Comment: I see, something I don't understand is how to reference the Object in the Hash Map. Would you kindly show me an example through some pseudocode?